# Sharing JDO classes between google app engine and other platforms

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jdo

I have a perfectly running GAE project using JDO 2. I use IntellJ to develop with.

I want to move some of my awesome code onto platforms other than GAE, like Jetty. So, I want to create a module that can be used by both the GAE project and the jetty project to pretty much the same thing on the data layer. Structured as:

- GAEProject
- JettyProject
- SharedModule

I'm moving my PersistenceCapable JDO Classes to the SharedModule, everything compiles ok. JettyProject works just fine persisting data to a mysql db using the same code that once persisted to the app engine data store..

When I go to run the GAEProject, i get an error:

Google AppEngine Enhancer: SEVERE: Bundle "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" requires "org.datanucleus" version "3.2.4" but the resolved bundle has version "3.2.4" which is outside the expected range.

not helpful. It's a problem with the enhancer. I think I need to figure out how to get GAE Enhancer to enhance the classes in the second module. When i use IntellJ to configure the enhancer, it won't let me set directories to enhance to those outside the GAEProject.

Comment: So don't use the GAE enhancer plugin?, and use the DataNucleus enhancer via (after all DataNucleus requires the enhancement, so using its enhancer makes more sense to me). http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/guides/idea/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info - this would be part of the solution i'm sure. I installed the plugin, turned off app engine enhancement, and configured my project to use the datanucleus enhancer.  my classes were all detected in the settings menu but when I run the project i get "Persistent class "Class [classname] does not seem to have been enhanced.  You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output."  is it possible i need to add a step somewhere to run the enhancer as part of the build/run configuration?

Comment: No idea about the DN Idea plugin, someone else wrote it and I use Eclipse. Should have a log for what it is doing, somewhere?

Comment: Ok, to simplify i opened this question to take GAE and Idea out of the picture - if I can just get the class in the second module to be enhanced using maven i'd be closer to my goal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431412/using-jdo-persistent-classes-from-a-separate-module-with-datanucleus-maven-plugi

Comment: solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431412/using-jdo-persistent-classes-from-a-separate-module-with-datanucleus-maven-plugi