# Using JDO Persistent classes from a separate module with datanucleus maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, datanucleus

I have a working application that persists to a database using JDO - I want to use a PersistenceCapable class that's in a second java module. Although the app compiles a simple test gives the error:

> The class "com.hello.world.Foo" is not persistable This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

Ok, so the enhancer plugin is not running on the classes in the second module. I'm not sure what i need to do to point the enhancer at that module during the build.

- ParentProject
- Second Module: com.hello.world.Foo

ParentProject  pom.xml with relevant parts - problem is how do i point the enhancer at the second module containing my persistent class?

```
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>Second Module</groupId>
            <artifactId>Second Module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0-release</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: and how do you know the enhancer isn't running? The DN Maven plugin will print out to the console when running. Does it see the classes? if not then configure it to see them http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/enhancer.html#maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it - i had to add the exact same pom.xml config in the question to the second module and do a `mvn install` to get those classes enahnced before compiling the parent module. Working on both Jetty and GAE.  I thought, wrongly, that the parent module would enhance classes included in the module dependencies.

Thanks for your help DataNucleus!