# GAE Eclipse: Cross-Modules Referencing

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have a project setup with an EAR and two WAR projects (=modules) in Eclipse for Google AppEngine (GAE). **I would like to reference classes from module A in module B**. How do I do this?

**What I have done so far:**

I have added module A to the build path of module B. This solves the problem with the compiler, but it does not solve the problem of referencing classes during runtime. I receive a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

**Context:**

GAE modules share the same datastore, so I want to access the same persistence classes. These classes are defined and enhanced in module A. What is the best practive with this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to export your module A into a jar and add it to the war/WEB-INF/lib directory of module B.

Comment: I see. Do you know whether this is possible to achieve with a Maven project setup? I came across these two articles:

The first one talks about a "common project":
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10652

In the second one you can see a Maven dependency across modules:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431412/using-jdo-persistent-classes-from-a-separate-module-with-datanucleus-maven-plugi